# "bedrock" vs. "hardpan" for "very basis; foundation"

Tags: american-english, word-usage, vernacular

What's the difference between those terms in regard to their figurative sense?

Can they be used just about interchangeably?

Consider the following examples:

> *Ownership of land is the **bedrock** of democracy*.
>
> *Ownership of land is the **hardpan** of democracy*.

-and-

> *Mutual trust is the **bedrock** of a relationship*.
>
> *Mutual trust is the **hardpan** of a relationship*.

**bedrock** [Google Pictures](https://www.google.fr/search?q=bedrock&biw=381&bih=250&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq67XEo5fKAhWKbRQKHeLZA6MQ_AUIBigB):

> *noun*
>
> 1. *Geology*. unbroken solid rock, overlaid in most places by soil or rock fragments.
> 2. bottom layer; lowest stratum.
> 3. any firm foundation or basis: *Technical courses will be founded on a bedrock of sound, general education so as to produce a well-rounded engineer*.
> 4. the fundamental principles, as of a teaching, belief, or science:
>      Let's strip away the cant and get down to bedrock.
>
> *adjective*
>
> 5. basic; fundamental.
>
> Etymology: 1840-50, Americanism; bed + rock

**hardpan** [Google Pictures](https://www.google.fr/search?q=hardpan&biw=381&bih=250&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq67XEo5fKAhWKbRQKHeLZA6MQ_AUIBigB):

> *noun*
>
> 1. *Geology*. any layer of firm detrital matter, as of clay, underlying soft soil.
> 2. hard, unbroken ground.
> 3. the fundamental or basic aspect of anything; solid foundation; underlying reality: *the hardpan of mathematical theory.*
>
> Etymology: 1810-20, Americanism; hard + pan
>   [**Random House**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hardpan?s=t)

**hard pan**

> The hard stratum of earth lying beneath the soil; hence, figuratively, the firm, substantial, fundamental part or quality of anything; as, the hard pan of character, of a matter in dispute, etc. [**Webster's 1913 Dictionary**](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Hard%20pan)

Comment: Difference other than comparative commonness and recognizability? Difference other than contextual applicability index?

Comment: @JEL I mean, is there any significant difference that would justify using one rather than the other?

Comment: One wonders where you would have even come up with "hardpan" -- I've *never* seen it used figuratively, and it's really only known to those who have to dig in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between the two is that I hardly ever hear "hardpan" but "bedrock" is quite common.  A Google search of "hardpan" yielded 400,000 results; of "bedrock, nearly 15 million.  What's more, my spellcheck underlines "hardpan" as a word it doesn't recognize but not "bedrock."  Whereas this doesn't address any disparity in meaning, it does touch on a significant gap that exists between the two words in being readily understood.  A five-dollar word does you no good if everyone you use it on never has more than four fifty in their back pocket.

As for their meanings, I've always perceived a finespun difference between the two.  "Bedrock" has always seemed more ostensible, like "cornerstone."  It's openly known and utterly sublime to whatever one is figuratively building on it.  "Hardpan" has always seemed more tenebrous, and obscure.  It's underlying, but in a way that's more subliminal than sublime.  That isn't to say that it's secret but just beneath the surface of reality's broad daylight.  I don't know from where I ever drew that nuance, but I just asked my wife, and that's her take on it too, which leads me to believe there's something to it, even if it's subtle.

Comment: Personally, I (native Brit) have *never* heard of hardpan.

Comment: That's probably because you're not a geologist.  I know the term is obscure, so I decided to page through Google.  I went 6 pages, though 54 hits before I found a link where "hardpan" was used figuratively rather than the literally. Guess what the link was to?  That's right, to this page, to this question.  At that point, I stopped and patted myself (and my wife) on the back for even knowing what the word meant in this more figurative sense, for usage appears to be astoundingly rare.

Comment: If you're laying the foundations of your building on hardpan, you need to test and consider its bearing capacity; there will always be a limit on the size/mass of structure you can put on it. This isn't normally the case with bedrock. As I understand it, skyscrapers in Chicago (hardpan over fluid clay) require a much more sophisticated foundation design than those in Manhattan (bedrock); and there are other limitations (for example, basement capacity). So no, the two terms aren't interchangeable; there's a reason why 'bedrock' has acquired a widespread figurative use, and 'hardpan' hasn't.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard "hardpan" used figuratively, and when it is used (with its literal meaning) it's often accompanied by some cusswords.

"Bedrock" is the established metaphor for "firm foundation" or "strong underlying principles".  It generally has a positive connotation.  "Hardpan", to those who even know what it means, is apt to have a negative connotation, as it's difficult to deal with in many situations -- hard to dig in, of unknown bearing capacity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Hardpan" is compressed soil.  The force of gravity, or weight, of the soil above it has compressed it to the point that plants can't put roots into it.  Although it may be difficult to break up it doesn't have the same solidity as "bedrock". My guess is that "hardpan"'s usage dates from a more agrarian age than this one, so I would stick with "bedrock".

Comment: Actually, as normally used, "hardpan" refers to a material which largely lacks the organic material that would characterize "soil".  It's more like poorly made concrete.

Answer (score 0):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* notes this figurative use of *hardpan*. But it adds "Now rare."